# Compile and Runtime Error in VBA code to copy Excel to PowerPoint on Sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, runtime-error

I am trying to copy some contents of an Excel document to a PowerPoint presentation. I have a third file where I have the source location (This is a Excel file on SharePoint) and sink location (PowerPoint on SharePoint).There are some other details such as on which slide I want to publish the content and from where I need to pick it up.

However, when I ran this I am facing two errors -

- Compile Error (method or data member not found) -> Application.CutCopyMode = False
- Runtime Error(method thisworkbook of object _global failed) -> Set Adminsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExportToPPT()

Dim ppt_app As New PowerPoint.Application
Dim pre As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim slide As PowerPoint.slide
Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range

Dim vSheet$
Dim vRange$
Dim vWidth$
Dim vHeight As Double
Dim vTop As Double
Dim vLeft As Double
Dim expRng As Range
Dim vslidenum As Double

Dim Adminsh As Worksheet
Dim configRng As Range

Dim xlfile$
Dim pptfile$

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'This line below is showing error(run time error)
Set Adminsh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Admin")
Set configRng = Adminsh.Range("RangeLoop")

xlfile = Adminsh.[ExcelPath]
pptfile = Adminsh.[PPTPath]
 
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(xlfile)
Set pre = ppt_app.Presentations.Open(pptfile)



wb.Activate
For Each rng In configRng
    With Adminsh
        vSheet$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 2).Value
        vRange$ = .Cells(rng.Row, 3).Value
        
        vWidth = .Cells(rng.Row, 4).Value
        vHeight = .Cells(rng.Row, 5).Value
        vTop = .Cells(rng.Row, 6).Value
        vLeft = .Cells(rng.Row, 7).Value
        vslidenum = .Cells(rng.Row, 8).Value
    End With
    
    wb.Activate
    Sheets(vSheet$).Activate
    Set expRng = Sheets(vSheet$).Range(vRange$)
    expRng.Copy
    
    Set slide = pre.Slides(vslidenum)
    slide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteBitmap
    Set shp = slide.Shapes(1)
    
    With shp
        .Top = vTop
        .Left = vLeft
        .Width = vWidth
        .Height = vHeight
    
    End With
    
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set shp = Nothing
    Set slide = Nothing
    'This line below is showing error(compile error)
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    
    Set expRng = Nothing
    


Next rng

pre.Save

'pre.Close

Set pre = Nothing
Set ppt_app = Nothing
Set expRng = Nothing
wb.Close False
Set wb = Nothing




Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I am not able to resolve the errors. For the compile error, I have enabled all the libraries in the references section. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Have you tried `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook`? You also have a `wb` variable... maybe you meant that one?

Comment: What are the error code and description?? Is worksheet `Admin` on the workbook that runs the code?

Comment: Is this code meant to run in Excel, or in PPT?

Comment: Application.CutCopyMode should be set to either xlCopy or xlCut not to False?